# Why is "Java Application" missing from Launch Configuration menu

Tags: java, eclipse, visualvm

I'm using Eclipse Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0) which I installed with the Eclipse Installer, and trying to set things up so I can run my applications under VisualVM (I had been able to do this successfully before, but using Eclipse Neon).  However, I run into the following problem:   When I go to setup a run/debug configuration for an application, this list of Run Configuration types includes "Java Applet" but does NOT contain "Java Application"; however, it DOES include "Eclipse Application".   *Is it the case that I should be using the latter for Java applications?*

Comment: _Eclipse Application_ is something different than a _Java Application_. Please tell which IDE package you have installed, because there are different ones (_Help > About Eclipse IDE_) and also tell where _Run As > Java Application_ is missing (in the right-click menu or in _Run > Run Configurations..._; if right-click menu, on which file or folder did you right-click and what does the file contain?). If you are unsure, show an uncropped screenshot of the whole Eclipse window.

Comment: 2022-12 must be run with Java 17. In this setup you're trying, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @howlger.   It turned out I had not include "Java Application" in my run/debug launcher options under "Preferences".   When I fixed this, I was able to specify "VisualVM Launcher" in my run/debug configuration.